# decrease parquet file size in Databricks (more smaller files)

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I ran the following to z-order and also increase file size (from ~200mb to ~1gb):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.targetFileSize", "1000000000")
dt = delta.DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/mytable") 

dt.optimize().executeZOrderBy("TimeStamp")
```

Then I did some query tests and the queries were slower to my surprise. I would like to explore the query times I get with 100mb files. However when I run the following (note 1e8 bytes not 1e9)...

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.targetFileSize", "100000000")
dt = delta.DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/mytable") 

dt.optimize().executeZOrderBy("TimeStamp")
```

the run finishes instantly and nothing is changed.

Comment: Running optimize multiple times will not result in any changes.

Comment: I would have expected that if I changed the `targetFileSize` it would not be idempotent